# C# How can i get max value of primary key

Tags: c#, textbox, increment

My question is how can I get the max value of a primary key in a table, increment it by +1 then put that result in a specific textbox.Text to be later inserted to database as new record. Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have the primary key be an identity column and let the database take care of updating it?

Comment: There are dangers to doing this.  For example, 2 people both access the same page and get the same max id.  Now one posts before the other and the max id has now changed.  The 2nd person will result in a primary key conflict when they try to update.  I would suggest following Tims comment

Comment: I agree with you but in the update query i am using this     `string sql = "delete from [table_name] where ID = " +textbox1.Text+" ; ";`  how can i resolve this one. Using the identity set to true a_i, i will have to delete this textbox1 in order for it to work... how will i continue ?

Comment: Depending on your DB, there are different ways to return the PK after it has been auto-generated after the insert statement.  Once you get this PK, store it in a hidden field and refer to it whenever you want to perform updates.

Comment: I hope you're SQL really isn't unsanitized (`DELETE FROM [table_name] WHERE ID = <textbox value>`").   That's just begging for a SQL injection attack.  Take a look, learn, and apply parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

This may cause program to working slow if database contain tons of record, But it working well for me.

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
/*
Add record from primary key column to datatable
*/

//Add primary key from datatable to List<int>
List<int> primaryKeyList = new List<int>();
foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    primaryKeyList.Add(Int32.Parse(row[0].ToString()));
} 

int maxKey = primaryKeyList.Max();
primaryKeyList.Clear();
myDataTable.Dispose();
/*
Do whatever you want with maxKey
*/
```

or

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
/*
Add record from primary key column to datatable
*/

int maxKey = 0;
//Find max key
foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    if(Int32.Parse(row[0].ToString()) > maxKey) maxKey = Int32.Parse(row[0].ToString());
}

myDataTable.Dispose();
/*
Do whatever you want with maxKey
*/
```

Comment: While this does answer the question, it's really not a good idea for the application to be generating a primary key, for the reasons in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql Wamp. You can use this code. i hope this work.

```
string con = "SERVER=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=dbname";
private void getMaxID()
{
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(con);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT MAX(ID) as 'aydi' FROM data1");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = connect;
connect.Open();
MySqlDataReader dr;
try
}
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
txtID.Text = dr.GetString("aydi");
}
dr.Close();
{
catch(Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
if(connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
connect.Close();
}
}
}
```